# Connection property has not been initialized - VB.net ExecuteNonQuery Error

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

I have this error "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized" when trying to connect and add data from text-box into ".accdb" database file. Please have a look at the code below. It seems all good to me.
Cheers,
Stan

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection





Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "C:\Database7.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into MkX ([ID], [Project], [Rotor Number], [MLC thickness]) Values (?,?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Project", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Rotor Number", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))

    Try


        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        myConnection.Close()


        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
  End Class
```

Comment: Dont dispose of the command until *after* you use it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Have I dispose any command at all?